# python - multiprocessing stopped working after upgrading spyder 3.2.1

Tags: multiprocessing, ipython, anaconda, spyder

I was successfully running this code in spyder 3.1:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

I since installed spyder 3.2.1 by running the following:

```
conda install -c spyder-ide spyder
```

Since installing spyder, the above doesn't work any more. I get a long error messasge, which ends in the following:

```
  File "C:\Users\ywu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 172, in get_preparation_data
    main_mod_name = getattr(main_module.__spec__, "name", None)

AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__spec__'
```

I am running windows 10, spyder 3.2 and IPython. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you install spyder in the first place? (Why is this question tagged with Anaconda?)

Comment: I installed it when i installed anaconda. Thank you.

Comment: You should not use `pip` to upgrade packages that were installed by conda... I'm not sure if that's the issue here, but what I'd recommend is to remove Spyder (`pip uninstall spyder` and `conda remove spyder`) and then re-install spyder using conda, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thank you. I followed your directions to uninstall spyder, and then i installed spyder via the directions on spyder's anaconda package. I also changed the code to an easier example.

Comment: I am seeing from other threads that ipython is the issue here not necessarily spyder. Does anyone know if that's the case and if so, what's an alternative?

Comment: any update on this?